# Safari prompts for BasicAuth credentials on every request in WordPress admin area, but works fine on the rest of the site

Tags: htaccess, authentication, htpasswd

I have a WordPress website which is in development, and is hidden behind a BasicAuth password prompt. My root level `.htaccess` file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Login Details"
AuthUserFile /var/www/vhosts/site.tld/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

When accessing the front-end of the site, it seems to prompt once and then all is fine. When using the admin, we are seeing the prompt multiple times, despite ticking "remember password". It seems to mostly occur when using Safari - a prompt for almost all network requests on a page load.

The site is fully HTTPS, and I have cleared the Safari cache and closed/reopened the browser. An example request in the Apache access (SSL) log:

```
"GET /wp-content/themes/blender/screenshot.png HTTP/1.0" 401 1802 "https://www.example.com/wp-admin/themes.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.2 Safari/605.1.15"
```

Comment: Do other browser also have this problem, or have you only tested with Safari?  I found this Safari bug, but I'm not sure if it is the same issue: [37989 – Safari (still) doesn't always send basic credentials preemptively](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=37989)

Comment: “HTTP/1.0" - isn’t that a bit odd?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - It does occur on Chrome (and a couple of other people have said the same), but I see the prompt most repeatedly on Safari.

Comment: @MrWhite yes it is. The sites all report HTTP/2 when I test https://tools.keycdn.com/http2-test. If I look at the Chrome network tab, the various requests show `h2` in the protocol column - what can I check to see why it's using the old 1.0 protocol?